# Moai grid with tile colors

Tags: grid, lua, moai

I'm trying to create a grid for a game using the Moai SDK. Each tile in the grid should have the ability to be filled with a color.

So actually I have two questions:

- What is the best way to build a grid using Moai
- How can I fill each tile individually with a color

[image: The grid]

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the best way to build a grid using Moai

Moai has an object for creating grids: [MOAIGrid](http://getmoai.com/docs/class_m_o_a_i_grid.html). Using the framework's
jargon, you create a grid and give it a deck. Then you attach it to a prop and
add the prop to a layer. (That layer also needs a viewport which is attached
to a window.)

> How can I fill each tile individually with a color

A [Moai deck](http://getmoai.com/wiki/index.php?title=Understanding_Decks_and_Props) is an image or collection of images. If you wanted your
tiles to be different colors then you would create a deck with images of the
square in those colors.

## Example

This code will create a 4x4 grid in a window:

```lua
-- Open the window and create a viewport
MOAISim.openWindow("Example", 512, 512)
viewport = MOAIViewport.new()
viewport:setSize(512, 512)
viewport:setScale(512, 512)

-- Create a layer
layer = MOAILayer2D.new()
layer:setViewport(viewport)
MOAISim.pushRenderPass(layer)

-- Create a 4x4 grid of 64x64px squares
grid = MOAIGrid.new()
grid:initGrid(4, 4, 64)
grid:setRow(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
grid:setRow(2, 1, 1, 1, 1)
grid:setRow(3, 1, 1, 1, 1)
grid:setRow(4, 1, 1, 1, 1)

-- Load the image file
deck = MOAITileDeck2D.new()
deck:setTexture("squares.png")
deck:setSize(2, 2)

-- Make a prop with that grid and image set
prop = MOAIProp2D.new()
prop:setDeck(deck)
prop:setGrid(grid)
prop:setLoc(-256, -256)

-- Add it to the layer so it will be rendered
layer:insertProp(prop)
```

After that, if you want to change the color of a specific cell, use the
`setTile` method to choose which item in the deck that cell uses.

```lua
-- Change the color of cell 1,1 to the second item in the deck
grid:setTile(1, 1, 2)
```

Comment: In v1.4p0 (not sure exactly what version it was changed in) the line `grid:initGrid(4, 4, 64)` would be `grid:initRectGrid(4, 4, 64, 64)`

Answer (score 2):

Edited for entire code.

```
MOAISim.openWindow ( "test", 320, 480 )

viewport = MOAIViewport.new ()
viewport:setSize ( 320, 480 )
viewport:setScale ( 320, -480 )
viewport:setOffset(-1, 1)

layer = MOAILayer2D.new ()
layer:setViewport ( viewport )
MOAISim.pushRenderPass ( layer )


function createRect(x1,y1,x2,y2, R,G,B)
    local function onDraw()
        MOAIGfxDevice.setPenColor(R,G,B)
        MOAIDraw.fillRect(x1,y1,x1+x2,y1+y2) --This is the rect drawing line.
    end

    local gfxQuad = MOAIScriptDeck.new()
    gfxQuad:setRect(x1,y1,x2,y2)
    gfxQuad:setDrawCallback(onDraw)

    local prop = MOAIProp2D.new()
    prop:setDeck(gfxQuad)
    layer:insertProp ( prop )
    return prop
end

mapmaxx = 10
mapmaxy = 10
map={} --array to store map
for x = 1, mapmaxx do
    map[x] ={}
   for y = 1, mapmaxy do
       map[x][y] = createRect(x*20, y*20, 10, 10, x,y,x/y)
    end
end`
```

You should check out [Rapanui](https://github.com/ymobe/rapanui/), a high level API for Moai (where I paraphrased this code from)

Answer (score 1):

Building a grid is really just drawing a heap of squares in a grid formation.
I don't know Moai's api; but I expect you can just drawSquare(x,y,width,height,color)

so you have:

```
local width = 800
local height = 600
local color = { red=1, blue=1, green=1 }
for x=1 , 100 do
    for y=1, 100 do
        screen:drawSquare((x-1)*width,(y-1)*height,width,height,color)
    end
end
```

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear on my question. I'm porting my Corona game to Moai, so the logic is there, but I can't find the correct function(s) to draw a square and filling it with a color. Also I don't know if I should create each tile manually or if MOAIGrid would be an option.